# Can i show different chart types eg radar, sunburst, doughnut in one graph object using plotly subplots

Tags: python, charts, plotly

I have tried the below code to show a radar chart and a sunburst chart as two columns in one graph object

```
But I get the below error...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/em/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly/subplots.py", line 436, in make_subplots
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: 
The 'specs' argument to make_subplots must be a 2D list of dictionaries with dimensions (1 x 2).
    Received value of type <class 'list'>: [{'type': 'radar'}, {'type': 'polar'}]
```

is it possible to create this type of multiple chart types in one graph object using plotly.

Answer (score 0):

As subplots can be placed in many rows and cols, you have to provide 2D array in specs. So instead of `list of dicts` you have to pass `list of lists of dict`.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                    specs=[  # first row
                        [
                            {'type': 'radar'},  # first col
                            {'type': 'polar'}  # second col
                        ]
                    ])
```

You can also find more usages and examples in [docs](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.subplots.make_subplots.html).